# Alternative to self-join

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table- supplynetwork including four columns:

> CustomerID, SupplierID, Supplier_productID, Purchase_Year

.

I want to construct a customer-pair where both customers purchase same product from the same supplier in a focal year.
I use the `self-join` to do this in `BigQuery`.But it is too slow. Any alternative?

```sql
select distinct
  a.CustomerID as focal_CustomerID,
  b.CustomerID as linked_CustomerID,
  a.Purchase_Year,
  a.Supplier_productID
from 
  supplynetwork as a,
  supplynetwork as b
where 
  a.CustomerID<>b.CustomerID and
  a.Purchase_Year=b.Purchase_Year and
  a.Supplier_productID=b.Supplier_productID and
  a.SupplierID=b.SupplierID
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed. (Note that this is not the answer to your performance problem.)

Comment: You should switch to  `a.CustomerID < b.CustomerID` to avoid duplicates. As it is now you get both A, B and B, A.

Answer (score 0):

use join syntax and do index CustomerID column

```
select distinct
  a.CustomerID as focal_CustomerID,
  b.CustomerID as linked_CustomerID,
  a.Purchase_Year,
  a.Supplier_productID
from 
  supplynetwork as a join
  supplynetwork as b
  on   
  a.Purchase_Year=b.Purchase_Year and
  a.Supplier_productID=b.Supplier_productID and
  a.SupplierID=b.SupplierID
  where a.CustomerID<>b.CustomerID
```

Comment: Nope execution time will remain same ,whichever syntax you use.Indexing might help if it is not an oltp because indexes slows down with multiple inserts and updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation to get *all* customers that meet the conditions in a single row:

```
select Purchase_Year, Supplier_productID, SupplierID,
       array_agg(distinct CustomerID) as customers
from supplynetwork sn
group by Purchase_Year, Supplier_productID, SupplierID;
```

You can then get pairs using array operations:

```
with pss as (
      select Purchase_Year, Supplier_productID, SupplierID,
             array_agg(distinct CustomerID) as customers
      from supplynetwork sn
      group by Purchase_Year, Supplier_productID, SupplierID
     )
select c1, c2, pss.*
from pss cross join
     unnest(pss.customers) c1 cross join
     unnest(pss.customers) c2
where c1 < c2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CROSS JOIN`, which (even though does a cartesian) can probably give you a benefit of simplicity. Try this query below and see if it's cheaper than your baseline:

```
select 
   focal_CustomerID, 
   linked_CustomerID, 
   Purchase_Year, 
   Supplier_ProductID 
from (
  select 
     SupplierID, 
     Supplier_ProductID, 
     Purchase_Year, 
     array_agg(distinct CustomerID) as Customers
  from `mydataset.mytable`
  group by 1,2,3
), unnest(Customers) focal_CustomerID
cross join unnest(Customers) linked_CustomerID
where focal_CustomerID != linked_CustomerID
```